# Imagick convert pdf to jpg crash

Tags: pdf, crash, jpeg, imagick

Spent a long time installing `imagemagick` and the php extension imagick and I can convert images using the command prompt and the php extension.

I installed `ghostscript` for windows and tested it through the command prompt by opening a pdf file. It worked fine.

However, when I tried converting a pdf into a jpg, the command prompt crashes with no error message.

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

Comment: Exactly this happened to me recently as well. It used to work, but now on windows imagick crashes with no error message exactly on the line where it tries to open the pdf. I have checked and double checked that the file exists, that it is readable and that other files work. It's the same story: It crashes on opening a pdf and gives no error message.

Comment: I experience the same issue. Did you come up with a solution by now?

Comment: Still the same problem 2019. :/

Comment: Same thing here.... `magick.exe file.pdf file.jpg` crashes with no error message or log.

Comment: Okay, it works fine with ghostscript downgraded to 9.25 (I was using the latest 9.52 earlier)